# "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')" error when loading page in Angular

Tags: angular, frontend

I am pulling data from a mockapi service in angular. I pulled all the data without any problems, then I tried to access the details of the data with the id of any data in the list. I think the function I want all the data runs later and I get this error.

**app.component.ts file**

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  
  data:Array<any>
  userData!: User;
  
  constructor(private task: TaskService) {
    this.data = new Array<any>();
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
      this.runTask();
  }

  runTask() {
    this.task.getData().subscribe((data) =>{
      this.data = data;
    });
  }

  getUserData = (id: number) => {
    if (this.runTask == null) {
      return
    }
    this.task.getUserData(id).subscribe((res: User) => {
      console.log(res);
      this.userData = res;
    })
  }
}

export interface User{
  id: number,
  name: string,
  phone: number,
  website: string,
  company: any
}
```

**task.service file**

```
export class TaskService {

  readonly URL;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 
    this.URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/"
  }

  getData(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(this.URL);
  }

  getUserData(id: any) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.URL+id.id);
  }
}
```

**screenshot**

[*first load*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibcH9.png)

When I click on the view button, the data in the id I want comes. A modal is opened and when I close the modal, all the data is received.

I've been researching the problem for hours and couldn't find a solution.

Comment: maybe itd help to also include your html file. also correct me if im wrong but getUserData is only used when you click on one of the records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting (that I see in the screenshot) comes from your template file 'app.component.html' in line 90.
It seems you are trying to read the id from an undefined variable (a variable that has not been loaded (yet)).

Make sure that it is defined, you can for example test if the variable is truthy using 'NgIf' like below:

```
<div *ngIf="user">
  <span>{{user.id}}</span>&nbsp;
  <span>{{user.name}}</span>
</div>
```

To avoid errors of types passed to methods (like [the one found by Roy Christo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71281550/1761495)), try not to use the 'any' keyword.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed, thanks a lot. I used *ngIf="userData" in <tr> tag in my table and my problem was solved. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The **id** is a number in your component but it's use in the service as an object. update your service as below

```js
  getUserData(id: number) {
    return this.http.get<User>(this.URL + id);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but this didn't work :(

Comment: Do you have the same error?